# Bash: get 3 element from string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

folks
I have string

```
 str1="MVM GT RT BHHT SYSTEMG RW"
```

I need to get "BHHT" and add it to variable str2.

I shouldn't use file. I need something like this:

`str1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3`

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple :

```
str2=$(echo $str1 | cut -d' ' -f4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with variable expansion

```
# removes the first three fields ( # for the shortest prefix )
str2=${str1#* * * }

# removes all after next space ( %% for the largest suffix )
elem=${str2%% *}
```